# NSIS script to display a Readme link or a URL on Upgrade success finish page

Tags: nsis

My requirement is to display a read me or URL on Upgrade success finish page. Is it possible to display a readme or a URL link on the upgrade finish page? If yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

The [MUI](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html) finish page supports both a readme checkbox and a clickable URL:

```
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME "$instdir\readme.txt" ; Can also be a URL
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_LINK "Visit my homepage"
!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_LINK_LOCATION "http://example.com"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
```

You can even use MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_FUNCTION and get 3 URLs if you really needed to...

Comment: And if you want any other label (than 'Show Readme' as default) next to the checkbox, it is possible to specify it by `MUI_FINISHPAGE_SHOWREADME_TEXT`.

Comment: Is this possible on successful upgrade finish page?

Comment: I don't know what the upgrade finish page is, if it is not a part of MUI you should provide a link so we know what you are talking about...